# Weird PHP fatal error with one letter change

Tags: php, wordpress

We recently started having this problem; really odd.

**The error code is:**

> [15-Nov-2018 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:
>   require(blasses/class-woocommerce-product-finder-widget.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/naturesp/public_html/shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-finder/woocommerce-product-finder.php
>   on line 73

The file hasn't been changed, so we assumed it was a caching error - but deactivating and deleting caching plugins led to no change. So we're at a loss.

It happens randomly on different plugins. They are usually the same line within each plugin however, and never more than 2 at once.

It just changes one letter to `'blasses' or 'dlasses' from 'classes' or similar`.

If anyone has any idea, would be amazing...

Comment: who changed the name `classes` to `blasses` or `dlasses`?

Comment: Check if the reference at line 73 is hardcoded or dynamic -- if it's hardcoded someone changed your file. If it's dynamic, something changed the variable.

Comment: Can you share the code (woocommerce-product-finder.php around line 73)?

Comment: Hi Martin - thanks. Line 73 is correct (not hardcoded), and shows classes - we have to replicate the error, save the file, then revert to the original for the site to go back up.

Comment: This is the hard code at line 73, as at the time of the error;

require( 'classes/class-woocommerce-product-finder.php' );
 require( 'woocommerce-product-finder-functions.php' );
 require( 'classes/class-woocommerce-product-finder-widget.php' );

Line 73 is the last line as above.